# Securing API calls without token

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, css

I'm building an app and an API endpoint using PHP(I know what you thinking!). My issue is that if I ask user for username and password on opening the app for the first time, since I can't store these details locally because they could be compromised. I'd send these through Post request to server then generate a token depending on whether the user is the right one. After getting response I must store this token locally right? 
Yes!.  there's expiration for the token. After the token is expired, I don't want to ask user for their name and password but want to access API still authenticating as that user. How will I do this?

If I use Oauth it's still the same procedure right? I should store something locally. won't that be compromised? I'm very confused.

How does other apps work. I'm sure they doing something in the background. They ask us for credentials only once and all subsequent API calls will be secured. Won't the token expire in that case or what?

Can i secure API calls without storing anything locally? I don't want API to be accessed from anywhere else but app.

Answer (score 1):

Use android SharedPreferences. It should be very secure unless you deliberately expose it e.g. its accessible via an exported content provider missing the (android:exported="false") in the manifest. You can also use sqlite but there is no point of using a db table for one or two rows of data.You can also encrypt the user name and password to add one more security layer to protect rooted users.
Furthermore to protect the data in the network you should use ssl in the backend so no one can sniff the credentials.

Comment: SSL is quite secure, unless a man in a MITM attack is used. Encryption requires a key to be stored somewhere so nothing is really safe. I guess the key is to make it more difficult but finding the perfect solution is the same as winning the lottery 5 times in a row. In essence, Oauth is pretty safe just not bulletproof.